# Having a hard time with $\exp = \log$ equation

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

This is a hard one:

Take a look at $f_{\alpha} = \exp(x-\alpha)-\alpha$ and $g_{\alpha} = \log( x + \alpha) + \alpha, \quad \alpha > 0$

Part a):

For certain $\alpha > 0$ there exists a finite area between $f$ and $g$. There is only one unique value for $\alpha$ such that $f$ and $g$ intersect in one point. Calculate this value $\alpha$ such that $f$ and $g$ touch each over in one point.

(Hint: plotting shows that the value for $\alpha$ should be $\dfrac{1}{2}$. I dont want you to assume that $\dfrac{1}{2}$ does the job and proof it)

The equation $f = g$ is hard to solve because applying $\exp$ or $\log$ to both sides wont help.

Part b):

Now that you found the value for $\alpha$ you have to give a formular that **only** uses the current value of $\alpha$ to calculate the area between $f$ and $g$.

$A(\alpha) = \displaystyle\int_{x_0(\alpha)}^{x_1(\alpha)} f_\alpha(x)-g_\alpha(x) \ dx$ where $x_0, \ x_1$ are the intersections of $f$ and $g$.

Disclaimer: I already posted a similar question but the anwser were not helpful. Now I changed the question form.

Answer (score 1):

Solution for part a) (not part b))

We assume that for $\alpha_{0}$ $f,g$ intersects on only one single point $x_{\alpha_{0}}$

Then we have $h_\alpha(x)=f-g)$ having a local extremum on this point.

We are thus looking at an extremum of $h$, thus solving the following equation:

$h_{\alpha_0}'(x_{\alpha_{0}})=e^{x_{\alpha_{0}}-\alpha_0}-\frac{1}{x_{\alpha_{0}}+\alpha_0}=0$ or $(x_{\alpha_{0}}+\alpha_0)e^{x_{\alpha_{0}}-\alpha_0}=1$

There is an easy solution $x_{\alpha_{0}}=\alpha_0=\frac 12$

Answer (score 0):

Given,

f(x)=$e^{x-\alpha}-\alpha$

g(x)=$log(x+\alpha)+\alpha$

For this to be intersecting at a single point and touching their diffrentials at that point must be equal too.

f(x)=g(x)

$e^{x-\alpha}-\alpha$=$log(x+\alpha)+\alpha$

$log(e^{e^{x-\alpha}})-log(x+\alpha)=2\alpha$

$log\left(\frac{e^{e^{x-\alpha}}}{x+\alpha}\right)=2\alpha$

$\frac{e^{e^{x-\alpha}}}{x+\alpha}=e^{2\alpha}$

$e^{e^{x-\alpha}-2\alpha}=x+\alpha$-------------$1$

Also,

f'(x)=g'(x) ------------$2$

$e^{x-\alpha}=\frac{1}{x+\alpha}$

Substituting $1$ in $2$ we get,

$e^{e^{x-\alpha}-2\alpha+x-\alpha}$=1, which implies,

${e^{x-\alpha}-2\alpha+x-\alpha}$=0

$e^{x-\alpha}+x=3\alpha$

x=$log(3\alpha-x)+\alpha$ ---------------3

Since x is the point of intersection and it should have only solution eqn 3 must have only one solution. For this to happen x must be a tangent and intersecting $log(3\alpha-x)+\alpha$ at only one point.

Let y=$log(3\alpha-x)+\alpha$, then y'=1.

$\frac{1}{3\alpha-x}$=$1$

$3\alpha-x$=$1$

Substituting back we get $x=1/2$ and $\alpha=1/2$

This is solution of part a.

And of part b, If we are using the current solution of $\alpha$ then the graphs are touching only at one point and the enclosed area should be $0$.

I am certain about part a and please check about the part b.